# When to process beam forming algorithms?

Tags: communication, signal-processing, microphone, analysis

I am building a system that uses beam forming to locate noises at different spots. All of the spots will be in front of the microphones (180 degree range of spots).

My first question is if the beam forming algorithms have to be done when receiving the data from the microphones or is it possible to store the information raw and apply algorithms for beam forming after. I ask this because there is multiple locations at random times so we would have to modify the beam forming on the spot which would require faster, more expensive hardware. If we can store the data then apply algorithms we can save cost because we won't need as much speed.

Is identifying multiple noise locations at random even possible?

I am looking for specific sounds, so other sounds will need to be cancelled out or be able to be ignored. This is why I can't use a simple technique as where did the loudest sound came from.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have the capacity to store the raw data from all of the microphones, there is no reason you cannot run the algorithm later. What is the difference between processing the data directly from the mics and processing the stored data?

Comment: @DoxyLover idk about OP's exact situation, but sometimes it's far easier to fit/use a CD-quality binaural recording device in locations where a computer to decode the resultant signals wouldn't fit/survive/be portable enough.

Comment: The key to beam-forming as a post-processing stage is to have accurate time information for each sample, and location information for the microphones. If you have that you should be able to beam-form afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using 2 microphones, then you should be easily able to record your data using high sampling-speed stereo equipment. **However** your later measurement accuracy for detecting sound origin direction will be limited by the sampling speed of your recording equipment.

The further apart you place your mics, and the higher your sampling speed for the recording, the more accurately/precisely you'll be able to resolve sound origin angles.